# Access google cloud storage using the python api and private key - Bad Handshake

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to access my google storage bucket using the python google.cloud.storage api, but get an exception:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

I have created a service account in GCP, defined it as project owner and editor, as storage object creator and viewer. I also added it as the specific bucket object admin, creator and viewer. I created a private key (json) for this account through the credentials page, which I try to use with the python client. None of these worked.
The python code is attached bellow:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account_private_key.json')
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
blob = bucket.get_blob('text.txt')
print(blob.download_as_string())
```

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that is intercepting HTTPS traffic?

Comment: Not that I know of, I am running from a docker on a GCP compute engine instance. The interesting thing is that gsutil works from the same docker instance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your certificates. You can probably reproduce it with this code:

```
import requests
requests.get(
    # Arbitrary Google API URL
    'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/storage/v1/rest')
```

Most likely, your system either does not trust the certificate authority that signed Google's key (unlikely) or you're behind a firewall that is swapping out the real certificate with its own (very likely). You could try disabling certificate checking, which you wouldn't want to do in production, to see if that's the problem:

```
import requests
requests.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/storage/v1/rest',
    verify=False)
```

Comment: You are right, disabling certificate checking worked. I am running from a docker on a GCP instance, trying to access the google storage on the same project. Not sure what I should change in order to make it work.

Comment: Update: I started a new gcp engine instance, allowed the default service account to have full access to storage, gsutil worked from within the docker, but the python api still didn't work with the default credentials.